# vertical align multiple lines of text next to image - all centered

Tags: css, positioning, vertical-alignment

Not even sure if this is possible, but thought I would ask.  I have searched and tried numerous 'solutions' with nothing quite what I am looking for.

The container is 940 wide by 100 high.  I want to include an image with multiple lines of text to the right of it.  Both of these as a whole should be centered both horizontally and vertically within the 940x100.  I will not have a width for either the image or text as this will change - especially since I am using it in a slider.

While I can 'mimic' this with a top margin/padding on the inside container I would like to have something definite and not a guess with the margin/padding.

I am using this with flexslider so that is why the format is as below.

```
    <div id="awards">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>    
                    img - multiple lines of text
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


#awards .flexslider{
height:100px;
text-align:center;
width:940px;
margin:0 auto;
border:1px #dedede solid;
background:#f1f1f1;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
}
```

EDIT : This acts exactly how I want it to other than the fact it uses a table-based layout :

```
    <div id="awards">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:150px"><img alt="" height="24" src="/images/logo.png" width="150"></td>
                            <td>This is a test of the comment section and if I make this larger and larger?<br />test.com</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>            
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

#awards .flexslider{
color:#222222;
height:100px;
width:940px;
margin:0 auto;
border:1px #dedede solid;
background:#ffffff url('/images/bg_diag.png') repeat;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
}

#awards table{
width:auto;
height:100px;
margin:0 auto;
}

#awards table img{
margin-right:30px;
}

#awards table td{
height:100px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (edited version of original):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

#awards {
    width:940px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px #dedede solid;
    background:#f1f1f1;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

#awards .flexslider{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.flexslider ul {
    list-style: none; 
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.flexslider ul, .flexslider .img {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.img img {
    vertical-align: bottom; 
}


</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="awards">
        <div class="flexslider">

            <div class="img">
                <img src="image.gif">
            </div>

            <ul class="slides">
                <li>multiple lines of text</li>
                <li>multiple lines of text </li>
                <li>multiple lines of text</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: (New version to fit with flexslider setup)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

#awards {
    width:940px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px #dedede solid;
    background:#f1f1f1;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

ul.slides  {
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

.slides li {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.text {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.text, .img {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.img img {
    vertical-align: bottom; 
}


</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="awards">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <div class="img">
                        <img src="image.gif">
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <p>multiple lines of text<br>
                        multiple lines of text multiple lines of text multiple lines of text<br>
                        multiple lines of text</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but not even close to what I was looking for - the image and text as a whole should be centered within its container.

Comment: OK, I see. I've updated the code totally now. Hopefully that will be better. I've tested it in all browsers but IE and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Ach, cancel that. I was using an image 100px tall, which gave a false positive. Making the image smaller ruined the experiment, so back to the drawing board.

Comment: OK, I think I've got it now. Adding `height: 100%;` to `.flexslider` did the trick. (Normally, there's no height set on a container like that, but heck, I'll use it when I can.) Hope the code above helps. that's the best I can do. :)

Comment: Ralph, I will check this out right now.  In the meantime, I created exactly what I wanted functionality wise using a table which I added above.  I would like to stay away from using a table though if possible.

Comment: Actually, I've just made another edit, as I found that it broke terribly when contetn (such as the image) was much taller than 100px.

Comment: Ralph, this isn't going to work either.  I am using this with flexslider which is just a jquery slider script, but it uses each <li> to define a slide.  Each list item is its own slide and they go in the order listed.  Therefore, each slide must have everything within its list item.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's no problem. See the updated version above to fit with the flexslider setup (hopefully!)

Comment: The `div.text` element is unnecessary here, the paragraph could be set to table-cell instead of adding the extra element.

Comment: Alright, I had to modify some of the stuff you listed, but it does work... just not in IE7.  I guess IE7 doesn't support the table cell stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without adding extra elements:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/seKfn

```
#awards .flexslider {
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px #dedede solid;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -ms-border-radius: 6px;
  -o-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

ul.slides li {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  /* any width will do, fix for old Firefox */
  width: 100%;
}

ul.slides img {
  /* fallback for IE<10, hide from Safari */
  float: left;
}

ul.slides p {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
/* optional
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 auto;
  flex: 1 auto;
*/
}

<div id="awards">
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/50" />
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/50" />
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will work in just about everything other than IE<10.  I've provided a fallback for the older browsers, but it needs to be hidden from Safari.